# Security groups not allowing domain admin to view files

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, permissions, network-share

This should be very simple.  I have my Documents folders redirected to a share called //dc/documents.  It creates a folder under this share for each person and then creates a folder under that for My Documents.  The security permissions on this //dc/documents share are as follows:

- Share Permissions:

  - Everyone - Full Control
- NTFS Permissions:

  - Everyone (This Folder Only) - List Folder/Read Data, Read Attributes, Read Extended Attributes, Read Permissions
  - CREATOR OWNER (Subfolders and files only) - Full Control
  - SYSTEM (This folder, subfolders and files) - Full Control
  - Administrators (This folder, subfolders and files) - Full Control
  - Domain Admins (This folder, subfolders and files) - Full Control

My problem arises when I sign into the in-built administrator account on the PDC.  Though that account is part of the Domain Admins and Administrator groups, I do not have permission to view the subfolders and files. I don't see any inherited permissions that should prevent me from doing anything I want inside of these folders.  Is there some magical button I have to hit when opening the folders?  This is becoming increasingly frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the "Grant the user exclusive rights..." box ticked on the "Settings" tab of the folder redirection settings. Turn that off and the Folder Redirection client-side extension (CSE) will add "Administrators" to the permissions on the folders it creates.

Pesonally, I pre-create the subfolders for the users because the Folder Redirection CSE disables inheritance on the subfolders it creates (which I consider a Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup>). If you pre-create the folders and add "The User / Full Control" to the subfolder the Folder Redirection CSE will be happy and will leave the inheritance hierarchy on your folders intact.

If you want to "repair" the folders you already have you can use something like the `icacls` utility in a script to clean up the permissions. Assuming the subfolders are all named for the users' samAccountNames you could do something like the following:

```
FOR /D %%d in (E:\Home Directories\*) DO (
  TAKEOWN /f "E:\Home Directories\%%d" /r /d y 
  ICACLS "E:\Home Directories\%%d" /reset /T 
  ICACLS "E:\Home Directories\%%d" /grant:r "MYDOMAIN\%userDir%":(OI)(CI)F 
  ICACLS "E:\Home Directories\%%d" /setowner "MYDOMAIN\%userDir%" /T 
)
```

That'll give you a nice, clean inheritance hierarchy again w/ the user specified w/ "Full Control" permission at each subfolder.

Comment: Dang. It looks like you beat me to the punch Evan. Curses! ;)

Comment: @joeqwerty: Nah-- you beat me by a few seconds, actually.

Comment: Hmm... I did indeed...

Comment: Wow, that took all of 12 minutes to answer lol.  Thanks guys, I appreciate it.  I'm off to go recreate folders

Answer (score 0):

When configuring folder redirection via GPO there is an option to grant the user exclusive access to the redirected folders. This option is on by default and I suspect that even though you've tried to grant the permissions at the parent level that this GPO setting is causing the issue. Even though it appears that you've set the proper permissions at the parent level, Windows is removing those permissions as the redirected folders are being created due to the GPO setting.

If you change the GPO setting it will take affect for all new folders created but not existing folders. The easiest way around this might be to uncheck the GPO option, backup the data, delete the existing folders, let Windows recreate the folders, and restore the data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are just having problems with the UAC?

The UAC filters out your usage of the administrators group as a way of protecting you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx